# swiper.js controlling two instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

So I have setup two [**swiper.js**](http://idangero.us/swiper/) instances and I want to scroll both while using one of them.

***EDIT: My main goal is to recreate the main functionality on top of the swiper homepage.***

***EDIT2: I found [this link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JKYxKJ), but it appears that this uses an older version of swiper***.

Here is my config, only the first one works.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    //initialize swiper when document ready
    var swiperFront = new Swiper('.swiper-container-front', {
        // Optional parameters
        effect: 'coverflow',
        centeredSlides: true,
        direction: 'horizontal',
        slidesPerView: '3',
        loop: false,
        followFinger: true,
        controller: {
            control: [swiperFront, swiperBack],
            by: 'container',
        }
    });

    var swiperBack = new Swiper('.swiper-container-back', {
        // Optional parameters
        effect: 'fade',
        centeredSlides: true,
        slidesPerView: '3',
        loop: false,
    });

    swiperFront.params.controller.control = swiperBack;
    swiperBack.params.controller.control = swiperFront;

})
```

What am I doing wrong, and how to fix it?

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0va9ynt2/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main problem here was the outdated `swiper.js` version. Updated to `4.3.2`.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ajxmyL7v/

Answer (score 0):

**For documentation reasons.**

For this case the main difference in switching from Swiper v3 to v4 is to omit the `.params`. So instead of

```
mySwiper.params.control
```

without params and the new API

```
mySwiper.controller.control
```